# Protocol agnostic traffic routing to the same server based on targetted hostname

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, dns, routes

I am looking for ideas on how I can route incoming traffic to different hostnames to specific internal domains/IPs regardless of the protocol used, or to be able to identify the targetted hostname from within the network server.

Currently I have a NodeJS network server that handles incoming requests (regardless of the protocol/port).
I am in need of a way to determine the targetted hostname from within this server before the protocol has been detected.

Is there a way (potentially using a custom DNS implementation) that I can route all traffic from one hostname to another internal hostname/IP and then detect it.

Essentially, target1.com and target2.com will point to server.com - the handler for this needs to be able to then switch/route based on the targetted hostname.

This **must** be agnostic when it comes to the application protocol and external ports.

Thank-you in advance for any answers.

Comment: Network traffic is routed by the network address, not host name. In fact, neither IPv4 nor IPv6 have names in the IP header, only addresses. Packets are routed by the network protocol based on the address.

Comment: To add to what Ron said, an incoming TCP connection has no indication at all of the original hostname the caller might have started with.  There's only a source and target DNS address and port.  Only in certain protocols such as http, might there be an indication of the original hostname in the protocol.  So, a protocol agnostic scheme would only be operating at the TCP level where there's only an IP address (no hostname).

Comment: Now, you could give each hostname a separate IP address in DNS, but then if you're going to do that, I don't know why you'd route them all through one server in the first place - it seems you may as well just let the connections go right to the desired server since each host would have a separate IP address.

Comment: With the way the architecture works, they would all share the same codebase.
As such, the intended functionality is for them all to end up at the same server with a singular identifier.

From what it seems, however, I am going to need to employ the use of multiple IPs regardless of how I go about it.

I was just hoping for a creative way to avoid that.